# How to create theme in magento 2 stable version?

Tags: magento2, theme

How to create theme in magento 2 stable version?

There are tutorials available for Beta but not stable.

The steps I took are as follow :-

Created folder inside *app/design/frontend/Themevendorname/Themename/* in that created *theme.xml* & *composer.json*

but when I gone to admin `stores->configuration->General->Design` in that Design Theme drop-down........there the new theme is not displayed.

Here are the lines of composer.json

```
{
    "name": "themevendorname/theme-frontend-themename",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.4.11|~5.5.0",
        "magento/framework": "0.1.0-alpha107",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "0.1.0-alpha107",
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "frontend/themevendorname/themename"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Please check the image attached. Another thing is that I also created a folder named theme-frontend-themename inside vendor->magento folder & put the same folders here too but still not getting that theme in admin store->configuration->General->Design in that Design Theme drop-down.

Any Help Please.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any a module, theme or language in Magento2 stable, you need must create a `registration.php` file in directory contain module/theme/language.
Autoload of Composer it load all file `registration.php` before Magento2 run.

A `registration.php` file of a theme the following in `app/design/<area>/<Vendor>/<theme_name>/`:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'<area>/<VendorName>/<theme_name>',  
__DIR__
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much Bill...let me check that quickly & will be coming back :)

Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi Bill, can you please tell the exact location of module folder because there are many module folders available.

Comment: you need create it in `app/design/<area>/<Vendor>/<theme_name>/`

Comment: Yippiii, you the great Bill :)

I tried many times...not working but I put that file directly inside frontend/Vendorname/Themename/ (here) not inside language folder :) & it showed up in admin :)

Thanks Bill for your help for language. You did it :)

Just 1 question....why the default themes like blank & luma not there inside app/design/frontend/Magento/....?

Thanks again :)

Comment: I can't explain correct this question for you but i think in version stable, Magento want core file in `vendor/magento/*` and after Magento coming soon Market place, they want install, update all core file, third party via composer at `vendor` directory.

Comment: Hi, we recommend developing in app/code or app/design, which is how the Magento 2 GitHub is organized if you clone it. Your `registration.php` tells the component to install under `vendor` whenever someone deploys it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

-Add or copy from an existing theme.xml to your theme directory app/design/frontend//

-Configure it using the following example:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
 <title>New theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
 <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
 <media>
     <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
 </media>
```

-Add registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>',
    __DIR__
);
```